Understanding a proof that $[\mathbb{Z}[G] \otimes A]_G \cong A$
I am struggling to understand this solution to a problem sheet in my homological algebra class. We are given that $G$ is a finite group and that $A$ is Abelian and are considering $M = \mathbb{Z}[G] \otimes A$ as a $G$-module. Denoting by $M_G$ the coinvariants of $M$, the solution begins by finding that
$$ M_G \cong\left(\mathbb{Z}[G] \otimes A\right)/I_GM \cong I_G \otimes A $$
Where $I_G$ is the corresponding augmentation ideal (kernel of the augmentation map). They then consider the short exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $0 \rightarrow I_G \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[G] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$ (where the penultimate arrow is the augmentation map) and find the tail of the $\text{Tor}^\mathbb{Z}$ induced long exact sequence:
$$ \text{Tor}_1(\mathbb{Z},A) = 0 \rightarrow I_G \otimes A \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[G] \otimes A \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \otimes A \rightarrow 0$$
They now claim that this implies $M_G (\cong I_G \otimes A)\cong \mathbb{Z} \otimes A$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, but I cannot see how this follows? I see how it would follow if one can show that the kernel of the induced penultimate map is $\mathbb{Z} \otimes A$, but I do not see how we can deduce this immediately. I wonder if this requires a small trick/result we haven't been taught or if there is a simple explanation that I just can't see - any guidance would be appreciated!

$I_G \otimes A \cong \mathbb{Z} \otimes A$ is definitely not true in general: $I_G$ is free of rank $|G| - 1$, so this just says $A^{|G| - 1} \cong A$ which is generally false. Something is either missing or off here.

@BenSteffan after thinking it through, I realise that I misread the solution. Where the lecturer wrote $\mathbb{Z}[G] \otimes A/I_GM \cong I_G \otimes A$, they mean that $I_GM \cong I_G \otimes A$, not the entire quotient - the result is then just trivial since $M_G$ and $\mathbb{Z} \otimes A$ are both cokernels of the first map in the sequence. I'm very sorry for asking the question without thinking this through when it comes down to the lecturer using unclear notation :')

$$M_G\cong\Bbb Z\otimes_{\Bbb Z[G]}M=\Bbb Z\otimes_{\Bbb Z[G]}(\Bbb Z[G]\otimes_{\Bbb Z}A)\cong\Bbb Z\otimes_\Bbb ZA\cong A$$
Would be how I do it. I don't like the presented proof though.
You seem to be assuming, for no clear reason, that the first torsion of $A$ is zero. This theorem would be true even if $A$ did have torsion, so that's no good. However, since tensoring preserves quotients, all you need to know is that $\Bbb Z[G]\otimes A/I_G\otimes A\cong(\Bbb Z[G]/I_G)\otimes A\cong\Bbb Z\otimes A\cong A$, which is what you wanted.

Please see my comment on the question - this comes down to the lecturer using unclear notation which I then misinterpreted !! The result I was confused about is indeed not true in general which would explain why I was struggling to prove it ! Thank you for your concise explanation

there is a gap in your argumentation, in general tensoring not preserves quotients, ie if $0 \to L \to M \to N \to 0$ a ses of $R$-modules and $K$ another $R$-module, in general it's wrong that $(M/L) \otimes_R K \cong M \otimes_R K / N \otimes_R K$. This holds only in special cases, eg if $K$ or $N$ is flat $R$-mod (first follws from definition of flatness, second requires a lovely diagram chase; see somewhere in Stacks Project)

Or did I misunderstood what you meaned by "tensoring preserves quotients"?

@user267839 Tensoring is right exact. The cokernel of $L\otimes K\to M\otimes K$ is indeed $N\otimes K$, which is what I mean

yes, but the latter is only isomorphic to $ M \otimes_R K / \text{im}(L\otimes K\to M\otimes K)$,  not to $ M \otimes_R K / L \otimes_R K$, as $L\otimes K\to M\otimes K$ is not neccessarily injective. That was my concern. And if we specialize to situation in your answer I doubt that we can deduce $(\Bbb Z[G]\otimes A)/(I_G\otimes A)\cong(\Bbb Z[G]/I_G)\otimes A$. Does it make sense? (...assuming I added the parentheses in the way you intended to state it)

... ups, here this isomorphism indeed holds, but only because $\Bbb Z[G]/I_G \ cong \Bbb Z $ is trivialy flat over itself. So what you wrote in the answer holds, but it requires this as additional argument.

@user267839 I’m slightly abusing notation but the fact $L\otimes K\to M\otimes K$ isn’t generally injective is of no concern here. If you want to complain about that then really we should say, $M\otimes K/L\otimes K$ does not even make sense. But if you interpret this notation as just meaning the cokernel of $L\otimes K\to M\otimes K$ then everything I said is correct
